# Use sections of an article as chapters in a book

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, scrbook, scrartcl, structure

I'm working on an `scrartcl` which consists of several sections, all of them in separate files.

Now I want to use the same source files also in a part (not a chapter) of a `scrbook`.

In this second scenario, by including the sections from the article into the part of the book, the chapter level is missing.

Is there a good way to fix this? Remember that I'd like to use the same source files for both the article and the book.

So ideally there would be a way to include the files in such a way that all sections are treated as chapters, all subsections are treated as sections, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter

\begin{document}
 
\section{A section that becomes a chapter}
\subsection{A subsection that becomes a section}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection that becomes a subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was easier than I thought :) Thank you!